# on building docker image level=error msg="Can't close tar writer: io: read/write on closed pipe"

Tags: linux, docker, celery, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, celerybeat

```
time="2017-10-27T07:39:20Z" level=error msg="Can't add file /var/app/current/app/content_classifier/forest.pickle to tar: io: read/write on closed pipe" 
time="2017-10-27T07:39:20Z" level=error msg="Can't close tar writer: io: read/write on closed pipe"
Failed to build Docker image aws_beanstalk/staging-app:  tar writer: io: read/write on closed pipe" 
Error response from daemon: Untar error on re-exec cmd: fork/exec /proc/self/exe: cannot allocate memory. Check snapshot logs for details. (Executor::NonZeroExitStatus)
```

I have a Pickle object in django_app/content_classifer object. There is a class to predict the result and it's initializing itself when celery tasks file gets initialised.

`docker build` keeps failing after giving an error message as in the title.

Answer (score 99, accepted):

if you are on Mac, make sure docker desktop is running

Comment: Can't believe I fell for this! 

Comment: Simultaneously felt dumb and relieved after seeing this 

Comment: You mean Docker Desktop right?

Whether or not the docker hub website is running is out of my control.

Comment: In my case I had to close and reopen it :)

Answer (score 14):

I had same issue few minutes ago, when I found your issue :)
I had some files opened = they were used by another application(GIT)

Please make sure that no files are being used.

Hope it will help.

Comment: Thanks, a debugging session was still active.

Answer (score 9):

I had this problem in Ubuntu and `sudo service docker restart` fixed it

Answer (score 5):

The problem faced because the process that generates the pickle object has a diffrent user assigned then process that was accessing the pickle object.

I define the location for pickle object in the setting file.

```
picklefile = "usr/local/webapp/forest.pickle"
```

I simply added the step as following in Dockerfile.

```
RUN chown -R /user/local/webapp/
```

Comment: Where I can find the setting file?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem. If you are using Docker on Windows using Docker Toolbox you should first run the **Docker Quickstart Terminal**, otherwise, it will not work. Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this is an Input/Output error and the docker couldn't access the files it wants to. As suggested by @Luk3rson make sure that the files are not used by any other application. Try to debug the logs in `/var/log/`. May it help you.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error when I was using a [Docker context](https://docs.docker.com/engine/context/working-with-contexts/) for a remote Docker host. After reverting to the Docker daemon on my local machine (Linux) everything worked again.

Answer (score 0):

For me when I was running it with WSL 2, I just had to add `sudo` to the docker command and it was all good.

Answer (score 0):

Restart your docker hub if you are on Mac. Docker was already running but restarting it did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

Use this command to give permissions

```
sudo chmod 666 /var/run/docker.sock
```